# Data is not being displayed

Tags: android, kotlin

So what I am trying to do here is to fetch data from the api by thecocktaildb.com, but I don't get any data shown.

## Adapter:

`

```
class CocktailAdapter(private val cocktails: List<CocktailDetails>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CocktailAdapter.CocktailViewHolder>() {

    class CocktailViewHolder(val binding: CocktailListItemBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CocktailViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = CocktailListItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)

        return CocktailViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CocktailViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentCocktail = cocktails[position]
        holder.binding.apply {
            cocktail = currentCocktail.strDrink
            ivLiked.visibility = if (currentCocktail.favourite) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE

            Glide
                .with(root.context)
                .load(currentCocktail.strDrinkThumb)
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .into(ivImage)

            holder.binding.root.setOnClickListener {
                (it.context as MainActivity).supportFragmentManager.commit {
                    val bundle = Bundle()
                    bundle.putString("cocktail_name", currentCocktail.strDrink)
                    replace(R.id.container_view, CocktailDetailsFragment::class.java, bundle)
                    addToBackStack("cocktails_list_to_details")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return cocktails.size
    }
}
```

`

## Dao:

`

```
@Dao
interface CocktailDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM cocktails")
    suspend fun getCocktails(): List<CocktailDetails>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM cocktails WHERE strDrink=:name")
    suspend fun getCocktailByName(name: String): CocktailDetails

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insertAll(cocktails: List<CocktailDetails>)

    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun update(cocktail: CocktailDetails)
}
```

`

## Entity:

`

```
@Entity(tableName = "cocktails")
data class CocktailDetails(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "strDrink") var strDrink: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "strGlass") var strGlass: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "strDrinkThumb") var strDrinkThumb: String,
//    @ColumnInfo(name = "strIngredient") var strIngredient: String,
//    @ColumnInfo(name = "strMeasure") var strMeasure: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "strInstructions") var strInstructions: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "favourite") var favourite: Boolean
)
```

`

## AppDatabase:

`

```
package com.aleks.exam.db

import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import com.aleks.exam.db.dao.CocktailDao
import com.aleks.exam.db.entity.CocktailDetails

@Database(entities = [CocktailDetails::class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun cocktailDao(): CocktailDao
}
```

`

ViewModelFactory:
`

```
class CocktailViewModelFactory(
    private val cocktailRepository: CocktailRepository
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return CocktailViewModel(cocktailRepository) as T
    }
}
```

`

## Fragment:

`

```
class CocktailDetailsFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentCocktailDetailsBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val selectedCocktailName = arguments?.getString("cocktail_name", null)
        GlobalScope.launch {
            (activity as? MainActivity)?.cocktailViewModel?.getCocktailByName(
                selectedCocktailName ?: return@launch
            )
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentCocktailDetailsBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context))

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        observeData()
    }

    private fun observeData() {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            (activity as? MainActivity)?.cocktailViewModel?.selectedCocktail?.collect {
                binding.cocktail = it ?: return@collect

                (activity as? MainActivity)?.runOnUiThread {
                    setDataBinding()
                    Glide
                        .with(context ?: return@runOnUiThread)
                        .load(it.strDrinkThumb)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                        .into(binding.ivImage)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setDataBinding() {
        binding.cocktail ?: return
        if (binding.cocktail?.favourite == true) {
            binding.btnLike.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.star_big_on)
        } else {
            binding.btnLike.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.star_big_off)
        }

        binding.btnLike.setOnClickListener {
            val cocktail = binding.cocktail
            cocktail?.favourite = cocktail?.favourite != true

            if (cocktail?.favourite == true) {
                binding.btnLike.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.star_big_on)
            } else {
                binding.btnLike.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.star_big_off)
            }

            GlobalScope.launch {
                (activity as? MainActivity)?.cocktailViewModel?.updateFavourites(
                    cocktail ?: return@launch
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`

## Model:

`

```
data class CocktailDetailResponse (
    var strDrinkThumb: String,
    var strDrink: String?,
    var strGlass: String?,
//    var strIngredient:Ingredient,
//    var strMeasure:Measure,
    var strInstructions:String?
)
//data class Ingredient (
//    var strIngredient1:String,
//    var strIngredient2:String,
//    var strIngredient3:String,
//    var strIngredient4:String,
//    var strIngredient5:String,
//    var strIngredient6:String,
//    var strIngredient7:String,
//    var strIngredient8:String,
//    var strIngredient9:String,
//    var strIngredient10:String,
//    var strIngredient11:String,
//    var strIngredient12:String,
//    var strIngredient13:String,
//    var strIngredient14:String,
//    var strIngredient15:String
//)
//data class Measure(
//    var strMeasure1:String,
//    var strMeasure2:String,
//    var strMeasure3:String,
//    var strMeasure4:String,
//    var strMeasure5:String,
//    var strMeasure6:String,
//    var strMeasure7:String,
//    var strMeasure8:String,
//    var strMeasure9:String,
//    var strMeasure10:String,
//    var strMeasure11:String,
//    var strMeasure12:String,
//    var strMeasure13:String,
//    var strMeasure14:String,
//    var strMeasure15:String
//)
```

`

## Repository:

`

```
class CocktailRepository constructor(
    private val context: Context,
    private val cocktailService: CocktailService,
    private val cocktailDao: CocktailDao
) {
    suspend fun getCocktails(): List<CocktailDetails> {
        return try {
            if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(context)) {
                val cocktails = cocktailService.getCocktails().execute().body()
                val roomCocktails = cocktails?.map { mapResponseToDbModel(it) }
                cocktailDao.insertAll(roomCocktails ?: return arrayListOf())

            }

            cocktailDao.getCocktails()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            arrayListOf()
        }
    }

    suspend fun getCocktailByName(name: String): CocktailDetails? {
        return try {
            if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(context)) {
                val cocktails = cocktailService.getCocktailByName(name).execute().body()
                val roomCocktails = cocktails?.map { mapResponseToDbModel(it) }
                cocktailDao.insertAll(roomCocktails ?: return null)
            }

            return cocktailDao.getCocktailByName(name)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            null
        }
    }

    suspend fun updateCocktail(cocktail: CocktailDetails) {
        cocktailDao.update(cocktail)
    }

    private fun mapResponseToDbModel(response: CocktailDetailResponse): CocktailDetails {
        return CocktailDetails(
            strDrink = response.strDrink ?: "",
            strGlass = response.strGlass ?: "",
            strDrinkThumb = response.strDrinkThumb,
//            strIngredient = response.strIngredient.strIngredient1,
//            strMeasure = response.strMeasure.strMeasure1,
            strInstructions = response.strInstructions ?: "",
            favourite = false
        )
    }
}
```

`

## Service:

`

```
interface CocktailService {

    @GET("search.php?f=a")
    fun getCocktails(): Call<List<CocktailDetailResponse>>

    @GET("search.php?s={strDrink}")
    fun getCocktailByName(@Path("strDrink") name: String): Call<List<CocktailDetailResponse>>
}
```

`

## NetworkUtil:

`

```
object NetworkUtil {

    fun isConnected(context: Context): Boolean {
        val connectivityManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val capabilities =
            connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)
        if (capabilities != null) {
            return if (capabilities.hasTransport(TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                true
            } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                true
            } else capabilities.hasTransport(TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

`

## ViewModel:

`

```
class CocktailViewModel(
    private val cocktailRepository: CocktailRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private val cocktailsListStateFlow = MutableStateFlow<List<CocktailDetails>>(arrayListOf())

    private val selectedCocktailStateFlow = MutableStateFlow<CocktailDetails?>(null)

    val cocktailsList: StateFlow<List<CocktailDetails>> = cocktailsListStateFlow.asStateFlow()

    val selectedCocktail: StateFlow<CocktailDetails?> = selectedCocktailStateFlow.asStateFlow()

    suspend fun getCocktails() {
        val cocktails = cocktailRepository.getCocktails()
        cocktailsListStateFlow.value = cocktails
    }

    suspend fun getCocktailByName(name: String) {
        val cocktail = cocktailRepository.getCocktailByName(name)
        selectedCocktailStateFlow.value = cocktail ?: return
    }

    suspend fun updateFavourites(cocktail: CocktailDetails) {
        cocktailRepository.updateCocktail(cocktail)
        selectedCocktailStateFlow.value =
            selectedCocktailStateFlow.value?.copy(favourite = cocktail.favourite)
    }
}
```

`

## MainActivity:

`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private lateinit var cocktailService: CocktailService

    private lateinit var cocktailRepository: CocktailRepository

    lateinit var cocktailViewModel: CocktailViewModel

    lateinit var db: RoomDatabase

    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        setContentView(binding.root)

        init()
        observeData()

        if (!NetworkUtil.isConnected(this)) {
            Snackbar.make(
                binding.root,
                "No internet connection, information could be outdated",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        }

        GlobalScope.launch {
            cocktailViewModel.getCocktails()
        }
    }

    private fun init() {
        db = Room.databaseBuilder(
            applicationContext,
            AppDatabase::class.java,
            "cocktails_database"
        ).build()

        val cocktailDao = (db as AppDatabase).cocktailDao()
        cocktailService = retrofit.create(CocktailService::class.java)
        cocktailRepository = CocktailRepository(this, cocktailService, cocktailDao)
        val cocktailViewModelFactory = CocktailViewModelFactory(cocktailRepository)
        cocktailViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this, cocktailViewModelFactory)[CocktailViewModel::class.java]
    }

    private fun observeData() {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            cocktailViewModel.cocktailsList.collect {
                runOnUiThread {
                    val cocktails = it
                    val sortedCocktails = cocktails.sortedByDescending { it.favourite }
                    val adapter = CocktailAdapter(sortedCocktails)
                    binding.cocktailsList.adapter = adapter
                    binding.tvCocktailsCount.text = "Cocktails: ${it.size}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`

I want the Cocktails to be displayed in a list.

Comment: Hello, have you set a LayoutManager to your "binding.cocktailsList" RecyclerView?
Without that the list won't be visible.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).